# Jenkins/Hudson API Access with API Key Not Working

Tags: javascript, authentication, jenkins, hudson, api-key

I'm trying to access my Jenkins build though the api however am unsure whether it is possible to do with a straight forward URL.

I've basically built a local website in which I have something like:

```
var jsonAPI = "http://jenkinsurl.com/build/api/json"
```

However I need authenticated. So i found my API Token but how do I put it together - is it like:

```
var jsonAPI = "http://jenkinsurl.com/build/api/json?apitoken=xxxxxxx"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Token is basically like a password. You still need to supply a username/password pair at HTTP authentication.

You can try (replace `apitoken` with actual token):
`http://username:apitoken@jenkinsurl.com/build/api/json`
or with curl:
`curl -u username:apitoken http://jenkinsurl.com/build/api/json`

Comment: Thats not working.
http://username:apitoken@jenkinsurl.com/build/api/json
My jenkinsurl has a port number in there so there are 2 ":" colons. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: A port shouldn't be a problem

Comment: From what I can tell, you are working in JS. You need to figure how to pass "basic HTTP authentication" in JS, and supply username/apitoken to that.

Comment: Yep - thats it! Thanks